# Getting rid of Dialog Boxes and replacing with JLabel

Tags: java, applet

I am currently working on an applet and am having a bit of trouble finishing it off. My code works just fine however I need to change the final portion from a `JOptionDialog` Message Dialog into just a `JLabel` that gets added to the applet. I've tried every way I can think of and am still coming up short. My current code looks as followed:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Password extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    Container PW = getContentPane();
    JLabel password = new JLabel("Enter Password(and click OK):");
     Font font1 = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 18); 
    JTextField input = new JTextField(7);
    JButton enter = new JButton("OK");

    public void start() {
        PW.add(password);
          password.setFont(font1);
        PW.add(input);
        PW.add(enter);
        PW.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        enter.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String pass1 = input.getText();
        String passwords[] = {"Rosebud", "Redrum", "Jason", "Surrender",  "Dorothy"};
       for(int i=0;i<passwords.length;i++) {
           if (pass1.equalsIgnoreCase(passwords[i])) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Granted");
                return
        }
             else {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Denied");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Password extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    Container PW = getContentPane();
    JLabel password = new JLabel("Enter Password(and click OK):");
    JLabel message = new JLabel();
    Font font1 = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 18); 
    JTextField input = new JTextField(7);
    JButton enter = new JButton("OK");

    public void start() {
        PW.add(password);
        password.setFont(font1);
        PW.add(input);
        PW.add(enter);
        PW.add(message);
        PW.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        enter.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String pass1 = input.getText();
        String passwords[] = {"Rosebud", "Redrum", "Jason", "Surrender",  "Dorothy"};
        for(int i=0;i<passwords.length;i++) {
            if (pass1.equalsIgnoreCase(passwords[i])) {
                message.setText("Access Granted");
                            return;
            }
            else {
                message.setText("Access Denied");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its sample code so no alignment  is done it will show message next to button. You can change alignment as  you wish ;)

Comment: You are awesome, I really need to reread my Programming in Java book.

Comment: I swear I'd vote up if it let me but it says I have to have higher reputation to vote up, still kinda new to this site..